# Pegando dados via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Preciso pega conteudo de uma div. Na verdade estou contruindo um menu dinamico, aonde eu defino

```
<li class="menuLi">
  <div class="acao">-3</div>
  <div class="desc">Inicio</div>
</li>
```

Depois tenho um ajax que deve pegar esta `acao` e enviar para uma pagina para saber qual pagina irá carregar. Porem quando pego este ação não está vindo, o atributo vem como `undefined`.

O código js.

```
function carregarPaginas() {
    $(".menuLi").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var acao = $(this).attr('href');
        location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c='+acao;
    });
}
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` funcionaria se o seu LI fosse um A e tivesse um atributo `href`...

Comment: como fazer então ?

Comment: Cara, estranho esse menu... <br>
troca: var acao = $(this).attr('href');<br>
por: var acao = $(this).find('.acao').html(); Ps.: $(".menuLi").click... precisa estar mesmo dentro de uma função? Abs

Comment: não, preciso que quando clique ou no menu ou no sub menu ele puxa a pagina que vem com o código em ação. teria como formular uma resposta ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não está utilizando link em se `<li>`, portanto é impossível pegar o atributo `href`.

1. É recomendável que você atribua o evento `click` ao `.menuLi` no `ready` do documento.
2. Por estar registrando um `bind`, ele não deve estar dentro de uma função, uma vez que a função irá "bindar" várias vezes o mesmo evento, logo, **não** coloque o bind do `click` da classe `.menuLi` dentro de uma função e sim direto no `ready` do documento.

**Conclusão**

Seu HTML

```
<li class="menuLi">
  <div class="acao">-3</div>
  <div class="desc">Inicio</div>
</li>
```

O JavaScript correto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menuLi").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var acao = $(this).children('.acao').html();
        location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c='+acao;
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/ehcg5qzu/1/)

Comment: Porem e quando eu tiver um sub menu este código seu não funciona. Como adaptá-lo para tal feito.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues, eu só indiquei daquela maneira pois foi o modelo inicial que passou, mas me diga, o que acha de atribuímos o evento de click ao div `acao`? Ou precisa ser no ,`menuLi` mesmo? Se precisar eu ajusto para como você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
  var resposta = $(this).attr('href');
  alert(resposta);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="login.html"> Login</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="menu.html"> Menu</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua intenção era pegar a ação definida na primeira div interna do menu selecionado, então basta substituir o trecho `var acao = $(this).attr('href');` por

```
var acao = $(this).find(".acao").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tenta isso:

```
var acao = $(".acao").html();
```